# JS : Objects into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, jsobject

i'm trying to create object named client. and put it into a array. And after this, read the name of the 1st client.

Exemple :

```
client1 {nom : "marco", prenom : "chedel", adresseMail : "ssss@ggg.com"};
```

and put this client into an array like bellow.

```
listClients[client1]
```

**what i did :**

```
var listClients = [];
var client1 = {nom : "chedel",prenom:"Marco",adresseMail:"marco@gmail.com"};
listClients.push(client1);
var client2 = {nom : "De Almeida",prenom:"Jorge",adresseMail:"jorge@gmail.com"};
listClients.push(client2);


function afficheClients(tableau){
  for (i=0;i<tableau.length;i++)
    {
      var c = tableau[i];
      document.write(c[adresseMail]); 
     // This ^^ doesn't work, it says :adresseMail isn't definied in c
    }
}

afficheClients(listClients);
```

Comment: First: Don't use `document.write`. Second: you have a syntax error. Try `c.addresseMail` instead of `c[addresseMail]`

Comment: The issue was that `adresseMail` didn't have string delimiters around it ie. you could use `c["adresseMail"]`.  heres a fiddle using jQuery to create list items for each mail address http://jsfiddle.net/kvPWr/.  (In the example I use the dot notation)  I'd strongly recommend using console.log to view stuff and Chrome DevTools to debug rather than document.write, it'll give you a lot more information that will help solve stuff like this :)

Comment: @NickHusher, i'm using document.write because my professor theaches that way.. what can i use instead ? thx !

Comment: `document.write` has a lot of gotchas and is a dangerous language feature to become dependent on. Instead, you could use direct DOM manipulation; [Here's a very simple example](http://jsbin.com/IdAGije/1/edit) (jsbin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're treating `adressMail` as a variable and not as a string:

use

```
document.write(c["adresseMail"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to access properties of an object:

```
obj.prop
obj['prop']
```

You are doing the following mixture which doesn't work: `obj[prop]`.

Fix your code to `c.adresseMail` or `c['adresseMail']` and it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Either reference it using a string:

```
document.write(c['adresseMail']);
```

or using dot notation:

```
document.write(c.adresseMail);
```

And, yes - `document.write` should be avoided.